# Uso del operador Ternario en JSP con JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, operador-ternario, taglib

estoy comenzando a utilizar los taglib en JSP y estoy intentando hacer uso del operador ternario, pero al ejecutar el JSP me aparecen errores de compilación tal como:

> tag = 'out' / attribute = 'value': An error occurred while parsing
>   custom action attribute "value" with value
>   "${requestScope.msjError!=''? 'Mensaje si es verdadera' : 'Mensaje si
>   es falso'}": Encountered "?", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt",
>   "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+",
>   "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||"]

Así es como tengo mi código:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${requestScope.error=='S'}">
        <p id="msjError"><c:out value="${requestScope.msjError}" /></p> <!--Imprime el msj de Error -->
    </c:when>    
    <c:otherwise>
        <p id="msj"><c:out value="${requestScope.msj!=''? 'Mensaje si es verdadero' : 'Mensaje si es falso'}" /></p>
    </c:otherwise>     
</c:choose> 
</body>
</html>
```

Ya he buscado en google y los ejemplo que he encontrado son similares al código que yo tengo, los he querido implementar pero me marca los mismos errores de compilación, que al parecer no reconoce el operador ternario "?".

Si alguien tiene alguna observación se los agradeceré. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código como está me funcionó correctamente, lo que tuve que cambiar fue la uri del taglib que parece estar desactualizada (fijate que dice **jsp**):

```
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>
```

Por la dudas que dejo abajo el tag y el la configuración que tengo de jsp.

```
<c:set var="msj" value="" scope="request"/>
<p id="msj"><c:out value="${ (requestScope.msj != '') ? 'Mensaje si es verdadero' : 'Mensaje si es falso'}" /></p>
```

Configuración:

```
<!-- Servlet & Jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.